# How can I reuse the parse method of my scrapy Spider-based spider in an inheriting CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I currently have a Spider-based spider that I wrote for crawling an input JSON array of `start_urls`:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from foo.items import AtlanticFirearmsItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader

import json
import datetime
import re

class AtlanticFirearmsSpider(Spider):
    name = "atlantic_firearms"
    allowed_domains = ["atlanticfirearms.com"]

    def __init__(self, start_urls='[]', *args, **kwargs):
      super(AtlanticFirearmsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.start_urls = json.loads(start_urls)

    def parse(self, response):
      l = ItemLoader(item=AtlanticFirearmsItem(), response=response)
      product = l.load_item()
      return product
```

I can call it from the command line like so, and it does a wonderful job:

```
scrapy crawl atlantic_firearms -a start_urls='["http://www.atlanticfirearms.com/component/virtuemart/shipping-rifles/ak-47-receiver-aam-47-detail.html", "http://www.atlanticfirearms.com/component/virtuemart/shipping-accessories/nitride-ak47-7-62x39mm-barrel-detail.html"]'
```

However, I'm trying to add a CrawlSpider-based spider for crawling the entire site that inherits from it and re-uses the `parse` method logic.  My first attempt looked like this:

```
class AtlanticFirearmsCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider, AtlanticFirearmsSpider):
    name = "atlantic_firearms_crawler"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.atlanticfirearms.com"
    ]
    rules = (
        # I know, I need to update these to LxmlLinkExtractor
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['detail.html']), callback='parse'),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[], deny=['/bro', '/news', '/howtobuy', '/component/search', 'askquestion'])),
    )
```

Running this spider with

```
scrapy crawl atlantic_firearms_crawler
```

crawls the site but never parses any items.  I think it's because [CrawlSpider apparently has its own definition of `parse`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules), so somehow I'm screwing things up.

When I change `callback='parse'` to `callback='parse_item'` and rename the `parse` method in `AtlanticFirearmsSpider` to `parse_item`, it works wonderfully, crawling the whole site and parsing items successfully.  But then if I try to call my original `atlantic_firearms` spider again, it errors out with `NotImplementedError`, apparently because Spider-based spiders really want one to define the parse method as `parse`.

What's the best way for me to re-use my logic between these spiders so that I can both feed a JSON array of `start_urls` as well as do full-site crawls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *avoid multiple inheritance here*.

Combine both spiders in a single one. If `start_urls` would be passed from the command-line - it would behave like a `CrawlSpider`, otherwise like a regular spider:

```
from scrapy import Item
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from foo.items import AtlanticFirearmsItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

import json


class AtlanticFirearmsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "atlantic_firearms"
    allowed_domains = ["atlanticfirearms.com"]

    def __init__(self, start_urls=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if start_urls:
            self.start_urls = json.loads(start_urls)
            self.rules = []
            self.parse = self.parse_response
        else:
            self.start_urls = ["http://www.atlanticfirearms.com/"]
            self.rules = [
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['detail.html']), callback='parse_response'),
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[], deny=['/bro', '/news', '/howtobuy', '/component/search', 'askquestion']))
            ]

        super(AtlanticFirearmsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_response(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=AtlanticFirearmsItem(), response=response)
        product = l.load_item()
        return product
```

---

Or, alternatively, just extract the logic inside the `parse()` method into a library function and call from both spiders that would not be related, separate spiders.

Comment: Cool idea. The recommended changes are working for full-site crawls (`scrapy crawl atlantic_firearms_crawler`), but if I do `scrapy crawl atlantic_firearms -a start_urls='[...]'` it doesn't parse anything, I think because there aren't any rules to tell it to use `parse_item` as the callback?  Am I missing something? edit: I'm kind of a Python noob, what would it look like to extract the parsing logic into a library function that I can re-use?  Is it something I can put in the same .py file?

Comment: That worked wonderfully! I regret I only have one upvote and accepted answer to give. Thanks for cleaning up my code a bit, it's helping me to grasp Python a little better.