# Base `Spider` class that delegates to a `SitemapSpider` or `CrawlSpider` depending on passed-in arguments?

Tags: scrapy

I previously [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080496/how-can-i-reuse-the-parse-method-of-my-scrapy-spider-based-spider-in-an-inheriti) about reusing the `parse` method I had written in order for my spider to behave differently depending on if it were passed in a `start_urls` argument or not.  If it were, it should *only* crawl those given URLs (don't follow), but if it were not, it should crawl the complete site (follow links).

The answer I got was very helpful and worked well, and resulted in a `CrawlSpider` definition like this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from foo.items import FooItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader

import json
import datetime
import re

class FooSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "foo"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def __init__(self, start_urls=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if start_urls:
            self.start_urls = json.loads(start_urls)
            self.rules = []
            self.parse = self.parse_response
        else:
            self.start_urls = ["http://example.com/"]
            self.rules = [
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[], deny=['/blog']), follow=True, callback='parse_response'),
            ]

        super(FooSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def parse_response(self, response):
      sel = Selector(response)
      if not(sel.css('div.product-view')):
          return None
      l = ItemLoader(item=FooItem(), response=response)
      product = l.load_item()
      return product
```

However, I've now just discovered that [example.com](http://example.com) has a sitemap that I can use, rather than having to crawl the entire site.  So I update my spider like so:

```
class FooSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "foo"
    sitemap_urls = ['http://example.com/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [('/', 'parse_response')]
```

But at this point I realize that `SitemapSpider` does not behave like `CrawlSpider`, and will not accept a `start_urls` in the same manner as my previous definition.  So is there a way to retain the previous behavior of a single spider named `"foo"` that delegates behavior based on the `start_urls` argument?

I don't know Python very well, and started thinking I could have a `FooSpider` base class that dynamically returns a subclass depending on the arguments, but now I'm thinking that probably isn't valid.  Sketch code (unworking) of what I started thinking about:

```
class FooSpider(Spider):
    name = "foo"

    def __init__(self, start_urls=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if start_urls:
            self.start_urls = json.loads(start_urls)
            FooCrawlSpider.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            FooSitemapSpider.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def parse_response(self, response):
      sel = Selector(response)
      if not(sel.css('div.product-view')):
          return None
      l = ItemLoader(item=FooItem(), response=response)
      product = l.load_item()
      return product

class FooCrawlSpider(CrawlSpider, FooSpider):
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    rules = []
    parse = self.parse_response

class FooSitemapSpider(SitemapSpider, FooSpider):
    sitemap_urls = ['http://example.com/sitemap.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [('/', 'parse_response')]
```

My lack of Python knowledge has caught up to me here.  Any ideas would be appreciated!  Worst case I could always just create separate spiders with different `name`s I suppose.